# Binary Semaphore as resource access controller: Multithreading POSIX

Tags: multithreading, posix

As per multithreading concepts, I have learned so far:

**MUTEX**: A `mutex_t` object can be used for managing access to a resource.

**BINARY SEMAPHORE**: A `sem_t` object can also be used to manage access to a resource

**Differenrce between two**: The concept of ownership i.e. in case of `mutex_t` the thread which locked the `mutex_t`, only it can unlock it. But in case of `sem_t`, there is no concpt of ownership and hence any thread can perform `sem_post()` on the `sem_t` object. This is the reson it can be used as `Event signals`.

Now suppose my crital section appears as:

A) Using `mutex_t`

```
typedef struct {
int count;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
}counter; 

counter count;
void increment(counter* c)
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&(c->mutex));
 (c->count)++;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&(c->mutex));
}
```

B) Using `sem_t`
**EDIT**: (Binary semaphore i.e. initialized to 1)

```
typedef struct {
int count;
sem_t sem;
}counter; 

counter count;
void increment(counter* c)
{
 sem_wait(&(c->sem));
 (c->count)++;
 sem_post(&(c->sem));
}
```

In case of `B)` till the time `sem` is `zero` no thread can enter the critical section and hence providing access control. But suppose due to some event `sem_post()` is executed by some other thread then it will allow access to critical section by other threads.

In this case this is actually a buggy situation and not a proper a access control.And hence programmer has to be careful with use of `binary semaphore` for resource access control.

I can conclude, it always better to use `mutex_t` for access control and `binary semaphore` for `event signalling`.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct or am I missing something?

Comment: FYI, this question might be better suited for another StackExchange site, such as CodeReview or SuperUser.

Comment: It's not really a buggy situation unless you make it a buggy situation.  Don't post when you aren't suppose to post.  That said, mutexes are a better fit for this if the are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes are very specific in their purpose. Like you said, they can only ever be released by the thread currently holding the mutex, and they only allow single entrancy. A mutex is effectively a semaphore initialized to a count of 1 that also verifies that the thread calling post is the thread that last called wait ('ownership' invariance).

Your example does not show the initalization conditions for your semaphore. If you wanted to use it in the same way as a mutex, it would have to be initialized to a count of 1.

Semaphores do have a wide range of uses, so I wouldn't call them 'unsafe'. For example, lets say that you have some resource that allows, say, 5 total consumers to be running. So you would protect that resource with a semaphore initialized to 5. As consumers invoke the resource, the semaphore will tick down until it hits zero, at which point it'll block new consumers until running consumers increment the semaphore. This is called a counting semaphore.

A great example of how to use a counting semaphore is a blocking queue - a simple Queue that has an Enqueue and a Dequeue method. Each Enqueue increments the semaphore, and each Dequeue decrements the semaphore. In this way, if the queue is empty, Dequeuers will be blocked.

Another example of how a semaphore could be used would be in a simple signaling situation, as you mention:

Thread A enqueues 10 jobs into a thread pool to run them in parallel. Each job has a semaphore associated with it that is initially set to 0. When the job has been completed by the thread pool, the thread pool posts to the jobs semaphore. Meanwhile, Thread A is waiting on each job's semaphore to find out when they complete.

So we see many uses for a semaphore:

- Making Mutexs, where the initial count = 1
- Protecting limited resources, where the initial count = N, the limit
- Counting queued work, where the initial count is = 0 and grows with queued work
- Signaling job completion, where the initial count = 0, and the semaphore is used to coordinate two threads.

I would remind you that locking in general is a topic that requires close attention - in systems that have complex interactions, its sometimes very easy to use too little locking, causing unintended concurrency, or too much locking, causing deadlocks.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but if you check headline of my question- it is binary semaphore's use as mutex for resource access control. I was comaparing `mutex_t` and `sem_t` (binary semaphore only) as resource access controller and whether my conclusion is correct or not?

Comment: I've answered your question, and more, by telling you the properties of a mutex in terms of a semaphore. A Mutex is nothing more than 1) a semaphore initialized to a count of 1 and 2) a locking primitive that requires release to be called by the owning thread (ownership invariance). There is no such thing as a "binary semaphore", at least, it's nothing more than a semaphore that's initialized to a count of 1. I've explained the properties of each, now you need to use your powers of inference to understand what that means.

Comment: And keep in mind that there are *many* uses for semaphores - they are used in a large range of modalities. You need to understand the whole picture. Yes, in software development, there are usually a hundred different ways of solving the same problem. I can't enumerate them all for you, so you have to think for yourself.